# Coexist two layers - for directfb and Qt

Tags: qt, fullscreen, layer, closed-captions, directfb

I'm a newbie... I have a browser application, written on Qt. It runs m3u8(hls) streams. The UI(which includes seek bar and other buttons-CC(Closed caption), fullscreen, volume change and mute), is being rendered using Qt. Whereas CC is displayed using directfb. The object gets three layers. In layer 0, I could get the whole of CC, but not display the seek bar. When layer 1 or 2 is used, I dont get CC fully, rather, I get only a portion of the caption. How do I make them co-exist?

My Question is :

Can I make both the layers coexist simultaneously?
Can I render the CC fully and at the right PTS(timestamp) even when layer 1 or 2 is used?

Comment: You forgot to tell us what `CC` means...

Comment: CC means closed caption